# Ubuntu boots to black screen but the screen is on

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphics-card, intel-graphics, integrated-graphics

After I installed and booted regularly, the screen is black but still turned on. It boots regularly under recovery mode but it doesn't suspend regularly or turn off the screen when the lid is closed in recovery mode.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1

Kernel: 5.15.0-57-generic kernel (in recovery mode)

CPU: Intel i5-1035G1

GPU: (integrated) Intel Iris Plus Graphics G1

Some command results from recovery mode:

Results of `lspci | grep VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G1 (Ice Lake) (rev 07)
```

Results of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G1 (Ice Lake) (rev 07)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Device 1c6c:078b
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Is Intel Iris Plus Graphics G1 not officially supported or is there a fix?

Comment: What OS did the computer come with?

Comment: @John It came with Windows 10 Home

Comment: Since the machine came with Windows, there may not be the Linux drivers you need. Not sure.